# Hide pop up windows behind main window in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I wondered if it was possible to hide a pop-up window behind the "main" window, the browser i am using is the newest Google Chrome.

It's because i have this javascript code that's being called everytime a user presses a button, that open's a window and then print and close the window.

But i would like it to open behind the "main" window so the user dont really see it open.

Is it possible?

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

And the button and the div with the text

```
<div class="mydivID" style="display:none;">
   Hello
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="PrintElem('.mydivID')" />
```

Is it in any way possible to do, if it's a browser setting, or change in the javascript, it doesn't matter.

Hope you can help :-)

Comment: How are you printing a web page without user interaction?

Comment: The user's interact, because they're pushing the button, and when they push it, the system will print the paper.

Comment: `mywindow.print();` will open a modal pop-up, where user has to click OK to actually finish the job. You want users to dig the pop-up beneath the main window every time? I'd say that's a bad user-experience ...

Comment: No it's absolutely the best experience for my customers, maybe if i explain. It's for a class, where my customers check in and when they press the check in button, it print's a small piece of paper the customers take to the class.

So it's important that it just print very smooth, no boxes :-)
It's not a script my customers use at home, only here at the school.
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: The last pop-up comes from the browser, you can't pass it. What if any arbitrary web page could use your printer programmatically without user to accept it? That would really be a security issue. If you want to print "smoothly", use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead of pop-up windows.